# how to set impala namenode rpc port number for python ibis or requests

Tags: python-requests, port, impala, ibis

I'm using 'ibis-framework'. I have

```
hdfs_client = ibis.hdfs_connect(...)
impala_client = ibis.impala.connect(..., hdfs_client=hdfs_client)
db = impala_client.database('abc')
data = pd.DataFrame(...)
db.create_table('tb_name', obj=data, format='parquet', force=True)
```

This failed because the `namenoderpcaddress` constructed by `requests` (called in ibis) has port 8020, whereas the correct one for me is 8022 (which is Cloudera recommended port; maybe for HA purposes).

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ip-0-0-0-0.ec2.internal', port=50075): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/tmp/ibis/pandas_7ae170c27ee6426e97e0f84aa9a2a778/0.csv?op=CREATE&user.name=user&namenoderpcaddress=ip-0-0-0-0.ec2.internal:8020&overwrite=false&user.name=user (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7feb44be49d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

(ip addresses in msg above were edited by me)

Any idea how I can tell ibis or requests this port number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`ibis.hdfs_connect`](http://docs.ibis-project.org/generated/ibis.hdfs_connect.html#ibis.hdfs_connect) takes a `port` argument that you can use to pass `8022`